# cupy.RawModule using name_expressions and nvcc and/or path

Tags: cupy

I am using CuPy for testing cuda kernels from a library. More specifically I use the `cupy.RawModule` to exploit the kernels in python. However, the kernels are templated and enclosed in a namespace. Before the `name_expressions` parameter to RawModule in CuPy 8.0.0, I had to copy the c++-mangled names into the `get_function()` method manually of the RawModule. Using `name_expressions` I thought that this should be possible, nevertheless, this requires the code to be compiled from source using the  `code` parameter in combination with `backend='nvrtc'`.

Should it be possible to enable (any of the below)?:

1. `name_expressions` in conjunction with `path`
2. `name_expressions` in conjunction with `backend='nvcc'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should it be possible to enable (any of the below)?:
>
> 1. 'name_expressions' in conjunction with 'path'
> 2. 'name_expressions' in conjunction with 'backend'='nvcc'

The answer is no for both questions.

The `name_expressions` feature requires the source code for just-in-time (JIT) compilation of your C++ template kernels using NVRTC, whereas the `path` argument is for loading external cubin, fatbin, or ptx code. If you want to compile an external source code, you can do so by loading it in Python first, and then pass it as the `code` argument:

```
with open('my_cuda_cpp_code.cu') as f:
    code = f.read()

mod = cp.RawModule(code=code, name_expressions=(...), ...)
```

Unfortunately unlike NVRTC, NVCC does not provide an API to return mangled names, so using NVCC is not possible. If you pass `backend='nvcc'` to RawModule, it'd raise an error.

Comment: Ah I see, then I continue too use 'path' to a precompiled .ptx file and copy my mangled names manually in hopes of NVCC getting a mangling extraction functionality in the future.

Comment: Is it because you don't have the CUDA C++ source code?

Comment: The kernels are written by me, and I use CuPy for unit testing of the kernels. However, I need to compile the .cu file containing the kernels with the same compiler flags to nvcc that is used in the production code.

Comment: Then you can load the source file like I did above, and set the compiler flags in the `options` argument: `mod = cp.RawModule(code=code, name_expressions=(...), backend='nvrtc', options=('-O3', ...))`.

Comment: Thanks, but all the compiler flags I use for `nvcc` are not supported by `nvrtc`. Trying to push through anyway, I run into two errors:
1) `cupy.cuda.compiler.CompileException: nvrtc: error: unrecognized option -O2 found` <br>
2) `cupy.cuda.compiler.CompileException: /path_to/myheader.h (3): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "cstdint"`
It does not find standard includes for some reason. After specifying `code=code`, I had to give the option `-I` in order for the source file's header to be found.

Comment: I see, yes it's a known issue that NVRTC does not cover most of C++ std libraries.

Comment: btw @mikaeltw I recently added Jitify support to CuPy. If you build CuPy from source, you could try setting `backend='nvrtc', jitify=True` in `RawModule` and see if your code compiles or not. What it does is to recursively search included headers until the compilation successes (if the code is correct). This feature will be included in the future v9.x releases.

Comment: Thanks for the update @leofang. I tried building from source and got the functionality to work. I have not looked more into it but get some internal error related to name parsing when trying out the `jitify=True` after resolving some local imports:
`cupy.cuda.compiler.CompileException: __nv_name_map(2): error: expected an expression

__nv_name_map(2): error: Error in parsing name expression for lowered name lookup. Input name expression was: " :"

__nv_name_map(3): error: identifier "_" is undefined`

Comment: Sounds like you were compiling template kernels but did not specify what to specialize. You likely need to set `name_expressions`.

Comment: I already specified `name_expressions` and the kernel in question is not a template kernel, but it is in a namespace. Producing a minimal example where the kernel is not enclosed in a namespace made it work. `name_expressions=('mynamespacename::mykernelname',)`, produced the errors above.

Comment: @mikaeltw Interesting. It'd be great if you could open a new SO question, post a reproducer there, and ping me to investigate further. According to the NVRTC documentation namespace kernels should work fine, but I don't think we test any cases like that.

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy n paste error and the namespace works. It had to do with the `name_expressions` argument not being iterable. Posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65087601/14483613 if you would like to consider adding a check for iterable on the `name_expressions` named argument.

Comment: Glad to know it works. Will answer your question in the other post.